# Upload image automatically to instagram with Selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium, java-8, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and I need to upload an image to instagram. But at the time the windows file selector opens I could not get it to search for the image and upload it automatically

[image]

Up to this point my application opens well, when it goes to the point of selecting the file it does not do it automatically

[image]

**I tried using the following codes without success**

```
driver.findElement(By.className(name)).send_keys('C:\\path-to-file\\file.jpg')
```

But it gives me back the value of the second photo, that is, it generates a file selector from the main folder and not the one that I pass through as a parameter

**I am using the following versions:**

```
Java: 8
Selenium: 3.14
ChromeDriver: 76
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by search... but you could pass a path to the system clipboard and then use a Java Robot to then paste it into the field. The send keys method assume the interface allows you to type into it... which is not always the case... if that works, then don't open the browse in the first place, just submit.

Answer (score 0):

Normal browsers don't allow JavaScript any access to the local disk. This is basic security. Imagine what would happen if you visit some site and it reads your local password file or any other important data without asking you.

If you want to upload files, take some standalone application or write a small utility that will do that. For instance, try instapy, you can find it [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/instapy/) or on [github](https://github.com/instagrambot/instapy-cli). It is a matter of taste, the other can prefer other tools. Just try several tools and see which fits your need better.

Comment: It's an application in java with selenium, and all I need is that at that point I automatically look for an image, it's nothing with javascript

Comment: You automate browser. Normal browsers like Chrome and FF do not allow uncontrolled access to the disk It does not matter how the browser is controlled: Via JavaScript in the page or via Web Driver. *I automatically look for an image* means actually *my code forces browser to look for an image*. Browser protects user from any code that attempts to access local file without asking the user. Why don't you want to write a HTTP client in Java or Python  to upload these images?

Comment: It is not for me, it is for a project that is being done. But what tool do you recommend to work with this?

Comment: I have extended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The window opened for file explorer is not part of the browser and therefore it can not be interacted with via selenium. The solution to this is a software called [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/). Use the following link for a guide on how to use AutoIt for file uploads : [Link](https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html)